# JAAS Liferay Integration

Tags: java, tomcat, ldap, liferay, jaas

I am using liferay6.0.6. I need to integrate liferay portal with JAAS module. I have created customized module using JAAS.

Due to some reason the JAAS login module is not getting invoked though I did required configurations mentioned liferay wiki (http://www.liferay.com/community/wiki/-/wiki/Main/Configuring+JAAS+with+OpenLDAP/maximized).

Could please provide any pointers to do the integration.

This is the startup log:

```
Jan 9, 2012 10:25:46 AM org.apache.catalina.core.AprLifecycleListener init
INFO: The APR based Apache Tomcat Native library which allows optimal performance in producti
on environments was not found on the java.library.path: C:\liferay-portal-6.0.6\tomcat-6.0.29
\jre1.6.0_20\win\bin;.;C:\Windows\Sun\Java\bin;C:\Windows\system32;C:\Windows;C:\Windows\syst
em32;C:\Windows;C:\Windows\System32\Wbem;C:\Windows\System32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\;C:\Progr
am Files\CREDANT\Shield v6.8\;C:\Program Files (x86)\SSH Communications Security\SSH Tectia\S
SH Tectia AUX;C:\Program Files (x86)\SSH Communications Security\SSH Tectia\SSH Tectia AUX\Su
pport binaries;C:\Program Files (x86)\SSH Communications Security\SSH Tectia\SSH Tectia Broke
r;C:\Program Files (x86)\SSH Communications Security\SSH Tectia\SSH Tectia Client;C:\Program
Files\Java\jdk1.6.0_25\bin;C:\Softwares\ant\bin;C:\Program Files (x86)\QuickTime\QTSystem\;C:
\Program Files\TortoiseSVN\bin
Jan 9, 2012 10:25:47 AM org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Protocol init
INFO: Initializing Coyote HTTP/1.1 on http-8080
Jan 9, 2012 10:25:47 AM org.apache.catalina.startup.Catalina load
INFO: Initialization processed in 1272 ms
Jan 9, 2012 10:25:47 AM org.apache.catalina.core.StandardService start
INFO: Starting service Catalina
Jan 9, 2012 10:25:47 AM org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngine start
INFO: Starting Servlet Engine: Apache Tomcat/6.0.29
Jan 9, 2012 10:25:47 AM org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig deployDescriptor
INFO: Deploying configuration descriptor ROOT.xml
Jan 9, 2012 10:25:47 AM org.apache.catalina.realm.JAASRealm setUseContextClassLoader
INFO: Setting useContextClassLoader = false
Loading jar:file:/C:/liferay-portal-6.0.6/tomcat-6.0.29/webapps/ROOT/WEB-INF/lib/portal-impl.jar!/system.properties
Loading jar:file:/C:/liferay-portal-6.0.6/tomcat-6.0.29/webapps/ROOT/WEB-INF/lib/portal-impl.jar!/portal.properties
Loading file:/C:/liferay-portal-6.0.6/tomcat-6.0.29/webapps/ROOT/WEB-INF/classes/portal-ext.properties
```